# Do Women Make Up 85% of All Consumer Purchases?

Tags: economics, gender

[This](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/b/9e28517f-8de1-4e59-bcda-ce536aa50bd6) video seems to be the source of the claim but I can't find what statistics they use to back it up.   [image]

These figures are duplicated at [She-Conomy](http://she-conomy.com/facts-on-women):

> Women account for 85% of all consumer purchases including everything from autos to health care:
>
> - 91% of New Homes
> - 66% PCs
> - 92% Vacations
> - 80% Healthcare
> - 65% New Cars
> - 89% Bank Accounts
> - 93% Food
> - 93% OTC Pharmaceuticals

Is there some legitimate study that shows this conclusion?

Comment: This is quite a different source of the claim, using it for quite different reasons from the duplicate question but the claim seems to be very similar. If we can find a more significant distinction, I we should reopen.

Comment: Yea that she-conomy site seems to be as far as the source of this figure goes, so I'm happy to put this one in the 50% of statistics that are just made up.

Comment: I don't think She-conomy is the source - just one of many sites copying the meme without a firm source.

Comment: This seems very unreasonable. What about single males? Don't they eat? It's near impossible to archieve 93% female food purchases